# in html captures click event on element that was displayed only on focus of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

in html, sometimes I have elements that I display only when another one gain focus : you click on a button, to make another one appear.

If then you click on this newly displayed element, it disappears immediately because the focus gets away from the first one.

**EDIT** : And this is what I want. That could be a drop down menu for example, and I want the list to appears when clicking the title, and I want it to disappear when clicking on an element in the list.

but I also want to capture the click event before the element go away, and I can't do that ! example :

```js
function make_action(element) {
    console.log(element);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += `<p>detected ${element.innerHTML}</p>`;
};
```

```css
#buttons {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#buttons:focus p {
    display: block;
}
#buttons p {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: none;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons" tabindex=0>
  <p    onclick="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onclick</p>
  <p    onfocus="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocus</p>
  <p  onfocusin="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocusin</p>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

I can workaround with the use of opacity and visibility with transition :

- opacity to have the ux of the instantaneous hide of the element but it's still present so you can click on it
- visibility is being delayed (sort of) with the transition, so for a moment you still have the element because it's still 'visible', but for human eyes it's not visible anymore

like that :

```js
function make_action(element) {
    console.log(element);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += `<p>detected ${element.innerHTML}</p>`;
};
```

```css
#buttons {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#buttons:focus p {
    /*
    display: block;
    */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
#buttons p {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    /*
    display: none;
    */
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons" tabindex=0>
  <p    onclick="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onclick</p>
  <p    onfocus="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocus</p>
  <p  onfocusin="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocusin</p>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

but, I'm not sure it's a good practice because the element is actually still on the page, so it can impact accessibility and maybe other things.

do you know a way to capture the click on the element, before it disappears ?

what I don't understand, is the following : the buttons disappears because the div lose it's focus. But, it loses it's focus BECAUSE a click occurred on one button, so why isn't this click on the button detected ? or how is it detectable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace you `:focus` with `:focus-within` which was created specially for this purpose.
And to do so that when clicked the elements loses focus, you can use the `blur` method to do so :

```js
function make_action(element) {
    console.log(element);
    element.blur()
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += `<p>detected ${element.innerHTML}</p>`;
};
```

```css
#buttons {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
/* there is the change */
#buttons:focus-within p {
    display: block;
}
#buttons p {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: none;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons" tabindex=0>
  <p    onclick="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onclick</p>
  <p    onfocus="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocus</p>
  <p  onfocusin="make_action(this)" tabindex=0>onfocusin</p>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: damn I'm sorry, I really didn't formulate my question well, I will edit it, i was tired... I WANT the buttons to disappear (for exemple, a drop down menu, you click on the title to make the list show up, then when you clock on an element of the list you want this element to fire action AND the list to disappear). It's just that I want to catch the click before the element disappears :)